# How check incoming changes with Bazaar?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

With Mercurial I do:

```
$ hg in
```

With SVN I do:

```
$ svn log -r BASE:HEAD
```

How do this with Bazaar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

bzr [missing](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/user-reference/missing-help.html)
will show you the unpulled and unmerged commits.